# Android App not working when downloaded via App Store or Google Play - ANR

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, google-play

I have an OpenGL based application which is working fine when I compile and build from eclipse and install it on my android device, however, when I try to publish the same app and install over the Google-Play, the application seems to crash, without giving an ANR dialog. I even tried installing my signed .apk from USB and it all works fine there. 
But the published Google-Play version is not working.

Is there any way that I can add some debug outputs on the published Google-play version?

I don't see any force-close or anything, it simply quits and following is the log. 
It seems to be crashing at my native c++ functions:

```
06-20 12:27:36.859: D/SensorManager(14842): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 1
06-20 12:27:36.859: D/SensorManager(14842): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 2
06-20 12:27:36.869: D/SensorManager(14842): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 3
06-20 12:27:36.869: D/SensorManager(14842): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 4
06-20 12:27:36.869: D/SensorManager(14842): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 5
06-20 12:27:36.869: D/SensorManager(14842): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 6
06-20 12:27:36.869: D/SensorManager(14842): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 0
06-20 12:27:36.889: I/GLThread(14842): noticed surfaceView surface lost tid=11
06-20 12:27:36.969: I/GLThread(14842): noticed surfaceView surface acquired tid=11
06-20 12:27:36.969: W/EglHelper(14842): start() tid=11
06-20 12:27:38.019: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #1 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:38.769: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #2 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:38.769: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
06-20 12:27:38.769: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510ff0 self=0x1a7d20
06-20 12:27:38.769: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=619240
06-20 12:27:38.769: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:38.769: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
06-20 12:27:38.769: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052aa30 self=0x1e8c68
06-20 12:27:38.769: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2001728
06-20 12:27:38.779: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:38.779: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:38.779: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.CameraVFP.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:38.779: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.c.run((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:39.529: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #3 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:39.529: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
06-20 12:27:39.529: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510ff0 self=0x1a7d20
06-20 12:27:39.529: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=619240
06-20 12:27:39.529: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:39.529: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
06-20 12:27:39.529: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052aa30 self=0x1e8c68
06-20 12:27:39.529: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2001728
06-20 12:27:39.539: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:39.539: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:39.539: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.CameraVFP.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:39.539: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.c.run((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:40.299: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #4 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:40.299: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
06-20 12:27:40.299: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510ff0 self=0x1a7d20
06-20 12:27:40.299: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=619240
06-20 12:27:40.299: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:40.299: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
06-20 12:27:40.299: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052aa30 self=0x1e8c68
06-20 12:27:40.299: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2001728
06-20 12:27:40.519: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:40.519: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:40.519: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.CameraVFP.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:40.519: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.c.run((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:41.269: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #5 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:41.269: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
06-20 12:27:41.269: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510ff0 self=0x1a7d20
06-20 12:27:41.269: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=619240
06-20 12:27:41.269: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:41.269: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
06-20 12:27:41.269: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052aa30 self=0x1e8c68
06-20 12:27:41.269: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2001728
06-20 12:27:42.319: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:42.319: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:42.319: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.CameraVFP.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:42.319: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.c.run((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:43.069: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #6 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:43.069: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
06-20 12:27:43.069: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510ff0 self=0x1a7d20
06-20 12:27:43.069: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=619240
06-20 12:27:43.069: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:43.069: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
06-20 12:27:43.069: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052aa30 self=0x1e8c68
06-20 12:27:43.069: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2001728
06-20 12:27:43.139: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:43.139: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:43.139: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.CameraVFP.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:43.139: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.c.run((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:43.899: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #7 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510ff0 self=0x1a7d20
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=619240
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052aa30 self=0x1e8c68
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2001728
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.CameraVFP.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:43.899: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.c.run((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:44.649: W/dalvikvm(14842): threadid=6: spin on suspend #8 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
06-20 12:27:44.649: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
06-20 12:27:44.649: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510ff0 self=0x1a7d20
06-20 12:27:44.649: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=619240
06-20 12:27:44.649: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:44.649: I/dalvikvm(14842): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
06-20 12:27:44.649: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052aa30 self=0x1e8c68
06-20 12:27:44.649: I/dalvikvm(14842):   | sysTid=14850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2001728
06-20 12:27:44.679: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit(Native Method)
06-20 12:27:44.679: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:44.679: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.CameraVFP.<init>((null):-1)
06-20 12:27:44.679: I/dalvikvm(14842):   at surreal.quake3.engine.c.run((null):-1)
```

Comment: Certainly you can add debug outputs via the android logging APIs in any code which you are building from source, java or native.  Doing so would be a good idea to help figure out where you get stuck, particularly look at surreal.quake3.engine.Camera9.nativeInit

Comment: Hi Chris, I added the Log outputs in my code, but after signing and uploading on the Google Play, the Log outputs does'not show up on the published version at all

Answer (score 0):

wow, this is a quite typical situation of native C code where you usually test the application compiling in debug mode and deliver in release mode.

Usually it changes a lot the optimization flags used by the compiler and the application becomes sensible to wrong memory pointers, NULL initialization and so on.

I advice to:

- Check if the android.mk file used for debugging and production, to compile your library has the same optimization settings. Check for the optimization level (i.e. LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3)
- take the apk you upload on the market and install the application from the apk. IN this way you can safely exclude any alteration (if any) done by the market itself
- If using OpenGL, it did happen to me once that the application crashes due to an OpenGL driver crash. In this case it is very hard to check the root causes of the problem. In my case it was due to a wrong VBO Identifier pointing to a dirty memory location. In my case, no ANR was generated too.
- Check for any "out of memory" situation. Again, sometimes, in C you have variables init to zero when you are in debugging and you use them to malloc memory. If you did not init them yourself, when you go and use it whit a compiled for release library, you will get a lot of surprises. One of them could be your crash type.
- Check for any other elements triggered by the "release" version. In one of my previous application, the application crashed due to an admob (advertisement) error which was not present in the test mode of the admob SDK. This could explain your behavior too.

I hope this helps in some way.

Cheers
Maurizio

Comment: Note from the question that the apk uploaded to market worked when installed via ADB, which would seem to rule out the release-vs-debug differences.  Pulling off the market downloaded APK and reinstalling it would be a good check though.  IIRC hearing the apk files may be changed on installation?, but the contents if extraced with a zip tool should be unchanged (otherwise the signatures would fail)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys. 
How do i download the apk from the Google-Store on my computer?
There are no adds in my application.

Comment: my flags are set as: 

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
                -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL \

Comment: adb pull /data/system/packages.xml and examine it to find the codepath of your apk, then adb pull that

Comment: hi Chris, so what would be the point of pulling that? How will i be able to debug that file ?